# How do I split this table row by row into two using PSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have a table (TABLE A) which records every origin and destination of a taxi order by time, now I want to find the first origin (i.e row 2), and then pair O and D row by row until last destination (i.e. row 9), the result should be like TABLE B. How do I achieve it?

[image: image here]

**TABLE A**

```
Time    GPS_Point                   Status
633     POINT(121.314917 31.149205) Destination
62323   POINT(121.535798 31.25828)  Origin
62328   POINT(121.535798 31.25828)  Destination
62332   POINT(121.535798 31.25828)  Origin
62429   POINT(121.5358 31.258278)   Destination
62637   POINT(121.535788 31.25827)  Origin
62647   POINT(121.535788 31.25827)  Destination
62731   POINT(121.535795 31.25826)  Origin
62741   POINT(121.535795 31.25826)  Destination
62812   POINT(121.535793 31.25826)  Origin
```

**TABLE B**

```
Origin_Time Origin_GPS_Point    Destination_Time    Destination_GPS_Point
62323   POINT(121.535798 31.25828)  62328   POINT(121.535798 31.25828)
62332   POINT(121.535798 31.25828)  62429   POINT(121.5358 31.258278)
62637   POINT(121.535788 31.25827)  62647   POINT(121.535788 31.25827)
62731   POINT(121.535795 31.25826)  62741   POINT(121.535795 31.25826)
```

Comment: next time, please try to put sample data as scripts and not (only) images and show your tries to obtain the result

Comment: @etsa thanks, I have added the sample data as scripts.

Comment: You are welcome. To help us to help you, I think it will be easier if you'll post - for your next questions - create and insert script, as in my answer...

Comment: Yes, the script is user-friendly, I will keep that in mind. The reason why I designed the image is to facilitate the illustration of the way I want the query to realize. I would be grateful if you make the image embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (but assuming some concepts, as sequentiality of Orig/Dest without any interruption) (I used some fake values for GPS_POINT, and 'O' as origin and 'D' as destination).

```
    CREATE TABLE TABLEA (TIME INT, GPS_POINT VARCHAR(10), STATUS VARCHAR(1));
    INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (633,'p1','D');
    INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (62323,'p2','O');
    INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (62328,'p3','D');
    INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (62332,'p4','O');
    INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (62429,'p5','D'); 
    INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (62637,'p6','O');
    INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (62647,'p7','D'); 
    INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (62650,'p8','O');

    SELECT ORIGIN_TIME, ORIGIN_GPS, DEST_TIME, DEST_GPS FROM 
     (SELECT TIME AS ORIGIN_TIME, GPS_POINT AS ORIGIN_GPS, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TIME) AS RN_O
    FROM TABLEA
    WHERE STATUS='O') A
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT TIME AS DEST_TIME, GPS_POINT AS DEST_GPS, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TIME) AS RN_D
                FROM TABLEA
                WHERE STATUS='D'
                AND TIME> (SELECT MIN(TIME) FROM TABLEA)
                ) B ON A.RN_O = B.RN_D
WHERE DEST_TIME IS NOT NULL /* IF YOU WANT OMITS LAST "O" ROW WITHOUT "D" */
    ;
```

Output:

```
    origin_time origin_gps  dest_time   dest_gps
1   62323   p2  62328   p3
2   62332   p4  62429   p5
3   62637   p6  62647   p7
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work fine to find the first origin, but it has a problem to find the last destination. Suppose I add `INSERT INTO TABLEA VALUES (62650,'p8','O');`. The output will have the row 4: `4 62650 p8 - -`, but I hope this single O would be omitted.

Comment: See my edited version, but as I told you you should consider/put some "requirements".

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. For this problem, I could figure it out using matrix manipulation, but as of using query, it is really challenging to me.

Comment: `TIME> (SELECT MIN(TIME) FROM TABLEA)` is really a smart way to omit the case where the first row is `D`. Similarly, I could imitate the solution by adding  `TIME< (SELECT MAX(TIME) FROM TABLEA)` after ` WHERE STATUS='O'` instead of using `WHERE DEST_TIME IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's so smart :-)  It was just to show you a "way", given your sample data.  I repeat: consider carefully the "requirements" for your data and in case, if possibile, "clean" (changing the SELECT) original data BEFORE using the query I suggested.

Comment: Is the "clean" in the context of "data cleaning"? If yes, I did it. I am not sure what "changing the SELECT" means but I thought it would be helpful to me, could you explain in detail?

Comment: I wrote "clean" to highlight the fact to be sure your data respect your assumptions (eg. "after one O there is always one D in order of time and you can't have a sequence O O D D but O D O D.  Using my query this is a requisite).  You can find others.   I wrote "changing the SELECT" to highlight the fact that the internal SELECT in my should be adapted according to your requisites.  My query was only a "suggestion" based on your sample data.  It's up to you to solve the whole picture you have.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select a.Time as 'Origin_Time', a.GPS_Point as 'Origin_GPS_Point', aa.Time as 'Destination_Time', aa.GPS_Point as 'Destination_GPS_Point'
from TABLE_A a
JOIN TABLE_A aa on a.GPS_Point=aa.GPS_Point and aa.Status='Destination' and a.Status='Origin'
```